# How to include leading zeros in Angular Material Date Picker?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

Using Angular Material 5.

I would like the date picker to display 01/01/2000 instead of 1/1/2000. I read the documentation, but I don't see anything regarding this.

Is there an easy way to implement this? Or will I ultimately have to create my own formatting somehow?

Comment: this section explicitly states it https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings

Answer (score 9):

You can provide a custom implementation of `MatDateFormats`.

Add `"@angular/material-moment-adapter"` to your npm dependencies.

Add the following information to your root module or a separate material module that you then reference.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
    MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
    DateAdapter,
    MatDateFormats
    } from '@angular/material';
import {
    MomentDateAdapter
} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

export const MY_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    },
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatDatepickerModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        MatDatepickerModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-US' },
        { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }
    ]
})
export class YourModule { }
```

Comment: Don't forget to install Moment.js: `npm i moment` (as I did )

Comment: this wont work if localization is involved right?